# Using Pig conditional operator to implement or?

Tags: apache-pig, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Let's say I have some table f, consisting of the following columns:

```
a, b
0, 1
0, 0
0, 0
0, 1
1, 0
1, 1
```

I want to create a new column, c, that is equal to a | b.

I've tried the following:

```
f = foreach f generate a, b, ((a or b) == 1) ? 1 : 0 as c;
```

but receive the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: NoViableAltException(91@[])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `OR` condition construction is not correct, Can you try this?

```
f = foreach f generate a, b, (((a==1) or (b==1))?1:0) AS c;
```

**Sample example:**
**input:**

```
0,1
0,0
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a:int,b:int);
B = foreach A generate a, b, (((a==1) or (b==1))?1:0) AS c;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(0,1,1)
(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)
(0,1,1)
(1,0,1)
(1,1,1)
```